# How to fix problem with ModelBuilder batch processing raster output names

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, batch, arccatalog, arcgis-10.3

I am using ModelBuilder in ArcCatalog 10.3 to automate a large workflow. As part of this process I am running my inputs as a list (batch processing) and using in-line variable substitution so that I can consistently name the output files. I had the entire model built and everything was working as expected until recently. Now for some raster tools the model is changing the output raster names from what I designate them to a default output name. For example if I have three outputs from euclidian distance all named PRH_Distance_%i% they are automatically being changed to EucDist_PRH_1, EucDist_PRH_2, EucDist_PRH_3 So far just euclidean distance, slope, plus, and aspect are affected. I was wondering if anyone else had encountered a situation like this or had any thoughts on how to get ArcCatalog to use the names I am designating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple things to consider about your problem:

1. GRID files can only be 9 characters long.
2. GRID files like to have lots of associated files with them, and model builder doesn't do a very good job of cleaning them up after processes have been run.

That said, I offer 3 solutions, since I have faced the exact same problem. I wasn't doing euclidean distances though, I was running watershed models.

1. Shorten your file names and...
2. Clean up leftover files and folders associated with the raster processes and...
3. Try python. This doesn't really have to be code-intensive so don't freak out haha.  You can export your model to python script and then just do small adjustments and use variables as replacement for the inline variable substitution. I am speaking honestly when I say this is very VERY basic python we are talking here.

Note: I have had no experience using 10.3, I am speaking from experience with 10.1 & 10.2.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Sean, where would I look for leftover files and folders you mentioned?

Comment: I'm not at my workstation right now, but if I recall correctly there might be a /dir/ folder within your workspace or output environment. There may also be some randomly named. aux files there too. If you are working within a database you might not have this issue actually.